# Java XML Getting nodes from node list crashes program

Tags: java, xml

**Hello there.** 
As the title suggests, I currently have an issue in
my program. In the animation loader, I have a method that should
load an animation from a collada file. It gets an Element as an input.
The first thing I do is to collect the animation data. I do this by getting a node list with

NodeList sources = element.getElementsByTagName("source");

And then I iterate through that node list:

```java
    for(int i = 0; i < sources.getLength(); i++)
    {
        // Problem occurs here:
        Element sourceElement = (Element) (sources.item(i));
        String id = sourceElement.getAttribute("id");
        if(id.equals(inputId))
            inputSource = FloatArraySource.loadFromElement(sourceElement);
        else if(id.equals(outputId))
            outputSource = Matrix4fSource.loadFromElement(sourceElement);
        else if(id.equals(interpolationId))
            interpolationSource = StringArraySource.loadFromElement(sourceElement);
    }
```

The problem occurs on the commented line, and it crashes (only sometimes) with this following exception

> Cannot invoke "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.changes()" because the return value of "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.ownerDocument()" is null

I can start the application three times in a row, and it crashes roughly one of four times.

The strangest thing is the fact that it runs perfectly fine in debug mode.

So, I'd be very happy if you could help me out with this issue.

-Budschie

**Edit:** Some people wanted that I post the full stack trace, so here it is:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.changes()" because the return value of "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.ownerDocument()" is null
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.changes(NodeImpl.java:1887)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.item(DeepNodeListImpl.java:125)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.getLength(DeepNodeListImpl.java:116)
    at de.budschie.engine.assets_management.newcollada.AnimationLoader.loadTransformAnimation(AnimationLoader.java:77)
    at de.budschie.engine.assets_management.newcollada.AnimationLoader.loadAnimation(AnimationLoader.java:31)
    at de.budschie.engine.assets_management.newcollada.ColladaLoader.loadCollada(ColladaLoader.java:60)
    at de.budschie.engine.assets_management.DefaultResourceLoader.loadAll(DefaultResourceLoader.java:75)
    at de.budschie.engine.main.MainWindow.gameLoop(MainWindow.java:192)
    at de.budschie.engine.main.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:81)
```

**Another edit:**
Here's the way I load my collada files:

```java
        Element colladaTag = null;
        try
        {
            colladaTag = getColladaTag(colladaFile);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Element libraryAnimations = (Element) colladaTag.getElementsByTagName("library_animations").item(0);
        Element libraryControllers = (Element) colladaTag.getElementsByTagName("library_controllers").item(0);
        Element libraryGeometries = (Element) colladaTag.getElementsByTagName("library_geometries").item(0);
        
        NodeList meshesList = null, controllersList = null;
        
        if(libraryGeometries != null)
        {
            meshesList = libraryGeometries.getElementsByTagName("geometry");
        }
        
        if(libraryControllers != null)
        {
            controllersList = libraryControllers.getElementsByTagName("controller");
        }
        
        if(libraryAnimations != null)
        {
            AnimationLoader.loadAnimation(colladaResult, libraryAnimations);
        }
```

And here's what "getColladaTag()" looks like:

```java
    private static Element getColladaTag(String path) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
            return doc.getDocumentElement();
        }
        catch(IOException | SAXException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("There is a problem with the file that couldn't be fixed.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

**Another small thing I noticed is that sometimes, the JVM itself crashes
because of an access violation in the string builder...**

**Very important edit:**
Whilest debugging I found out that I can't import `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl`.

My program doesn't throw a ClassNotFoundException though...
*So, could that be a reason why the GC is so confused?*

Comment: Sounds like the element you're getting the nodelist from is an orphan element (no parent document). How are you loading this document / how are you getting the element?

Comment: What is a `collada file` ? `The strangest thing is the fact that it runs perfectly fine in debug mode.` , seems your input is not always complete, maybe buffered data is lost ?

Comment: Collada is an interchange format (apparently xml) for 3D models. He's attempting to parse that xml but for whatever reason it looks like his application is possibly garbage collecting the document regarless of the element references he's holding.

Comment: updated my answer... which isn't an answer, but if you do it, your issue will probably go away (or at least get caught consistently)

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
  for(int i = 0; i < sources.getLength(); i++)
    {   
        // Problem occurs here:
        Element sourceElement = (Element) (sources.item(i));
```

to

```
  for ( Element sourceElement : sources )
     {
```

which would remove `sources.item(i)`. You could put `System.out.println("Index: " + i):` just above this line, which would give an indication of how far you get.

It looks like something is modifying the `sources` container while you are processing it.

Comment: sources is a NodeList not a Collection. The XML DOM is pre java 1.4 I think.

Comment: Ok. However between the time that `NodeList sources = element.getElementsByTagName("source");` was run and `Element sourceElement = (Element) (sources.item(i));` is run, the element at `i` went away, so something happened inside the NodeList, or whatever the NodeList keeps a reference to was changed.

Comment: Yes. If I had time I'd research how the DOM works. I think it's just a mass of HashMaps with an internal id / order system. Elements are ordered (IIRC..) and attributes are in any order etc.

Comment: So, my code can run several times, and it can process several animations, till the whole thing crashes. It's not likely that the NodeList is changed by my code, as the process of loading data into my engine is not multithreaded (yet)... So, my guess would be that the GC is just goofing around. There's still an unanswered question though: Why does it sometimes work, and why doesn't it work other times? And why are the error messages different? So, the most frustrating thing is that I can't look whats going on because this code never crashes in debug mode...

Answer (score 0):

```
private static <T extends YourColladaDataFormat> T loadColladaFile(String pathToXml) throws Exception {
     // loads the XML Document, walks through it and returns your workable data   model.

}
```

And then work with T.

Comment: So, what do you mean by "concrete reference"? I do not have my document available as an reference variable that is declared right after the class decleration. So, I have a method that gives me the collada tag. The document reference is just available from there. I'm not sure why the gc could collect the document reference though, as it must be referenced in some other kind of form, or else the root element that I'm returning would not have an parent thing. So, onto the way I load my stuff. First, I load the visual scene. Then I load animations, then geometry/skin and other vertex related stuff

Comment: So, to clearify, I do not have an concrete reference, but I thought that the gc wouldn't be so agressive that it collects stuff that is relevant for the current stack.

Comment: So, thanks for editing your answer :) . I tried your solution, but it still didn't work, as the gc still seems to "delete" the owner document reference. I tried to build up a more concrete reference, but it still didn't work.

Comment: But it could also be that I just didn't understand your answer. So, I'll  analyze the code a bit further, maybe I find some kind of concurrent operations in the node list.